# Move Sticky Nav Menu Below WordPress Tool bar when tool bar enabled

Tags: menus

I've created a sticky menu but its hidden behind the WordPress Toolbar when logged in. How do i move it below the toolbar when enabled and logged in?

I was looking for a conditional tag but couldn't find one for this. I guess there's a WordPress hook or filter that i could use.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean on the admin bar on the front end, that show up for logged in users.

The `body_class` function inserts a class called `admin-bar` when that is present. The admin bar is 28px high. You should be able to use that body class to conditionally relocate your sticky menu.

Answer (score 1):

```
body.admin-bar div.sticky.fixed { margin-top: 28px; }
```

Comment: Please explain your code rather than just post the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go about doing this is to simply move the admin bar to the bottom with this plugin. Its so simply, clean and less confusing. I use it for all my sticky menu sites.

LINK: http://wordpress.org/plugins/stick-admin-bar-to-bottom/

I know this doesnt "exactly" answer your questions buts its a great alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a conditional function to your `functions.php` file.

This works for me:

```
if ( is_admin_bar_showing() ) {     echo '<style type="text/css"> nav {margin-top: 32px;} </style>'; }
```

I checked in an incognito tab too. `nav` moves back to the top of the screen.

The only thing I haven't worked out how to do best is detecting viewport/nav size so that you can detect the size of either/or and then adjust the margin accordingly.